# Deleted record successfully but message can't be printed

Tags: ios, sqlite

I have put my  code here i am not getting ,what is the issue with alert message.

```
            NSString *deleteSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM FAVOURITE WHERE ID = %@", self.arrayID[[sender tag]]];
        const char *delete_stmt = [deleteSQL UTF8String];
        NSLog(@"insert query is %@",deleteSQL);
        NSLog(@"insert statement is %s",delete_stmt);
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(favouriteDB, delete_stmt, 1, &statement, NULL);
        NSLog(@"akh:%d",sqlite3_prepare_v2(favouriteDB, delete_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL));
        NSLog(@"akhdadsa:%d",SQLITE_DONE);
        sqlite3_step(statement);
        NSLog(@"this %d", sqlite3_step(statement));
        if (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            UIAlertView *myAlert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Message"
                                                              message:@"Successfully Remove From Favourite List"
                                                             delegate:self
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                    otherButtonTitles:nil];

            [myAlert1 show];

        }
```

Comment: why don't use Core Data ? It's very simple and powerful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have executed statement twice.

```
sqlite3_step(statement);
NSLog(@"this %d", sqlite3_step(statement));
if (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_DONE)
```

It should be

```
//sqlite3_step(statement);//delete this line 
NSLog(@"this %d", sqlite3_step(statement));
if (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_DONE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `sqlite3_step` twice.
The first call deletes the record, the second one then fails.